# react native android package repo (bintray)

Tags: android, reactjs, native, bintray

We currently build a mobile application which is still using jCenter for it's package repos. I am aware that jCenter has ben sunset, however I thought the repos would still be available for read-only.

As of yesterday I started getting the following error when building:

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-vlc-media-player:verifyReleaseResources'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-vlc-media-player:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.facebook.react:react-native:+.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-vlc-media-player
      > Failed to list versions for com.facebook.react:react-native.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.bintray.com/videolan/Android/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://dl.bintray.com/videolan/Android/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://dl.bintray.com/videolan/Android/com/facebook/react/react-native/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway
```

It appears the download service for bintray isn't functioning, and I'm unsure if this is gone completely, or if there is an issue with their read-only service.

We appear to only have this issue with the 'react-native-vlc-media-player' library.

We have plans to migrate to Maven, but it isn't feasible right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you use gradle `implementation`, I could solve 502 problem like below.

```
implementation 'com.xxx.yyy:a.b.c' // not use +
```

before script I wrote(502 problem occured)

```
implementation 'com.xxx.yyy:a.b.+' // use +
```